# SSIS cannot save to SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I am looking to save to a SQL Server database. In prior versions of Visual Studio, I had no issue doing this. I would go to:

```
File -> Save copy of package as
```

and it would give me the option to either save the package on the file system or to a SQL Server database.

Now the only option I get is to save to the file system.

How can I save to the SQL Server database again?

Answer (score 0):

"Save Copy of Package as..." is only available if the SSIS Project is using the Package Deployment Model. By default, new project's use the Project Deployment Model.

To convert, right click on the Project and select "Convert to Package Deployment Model"